# Linq - Take x-amount of distinct items from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I need to show the first 4 elements in a list of objects using a certain property. I only want to display the first four "Distinct" elements though. So, for example, if I have a list of 'Car' lets say and the Car object has a property called 'Color' as a string and the list looks something like:

```
  Car: red;
  Car: red;
  Car: blue;
  Car: green;
  Car: green;
  Car: orange;
  Car: purple;
```

Then I want code to print out the first four distinct elements "red, blue, green, orange" in this case.

So far I have something along the lines of:

```
  String.Join("," ,cars.Take(4).Distinct().Select(a => String.Format("{0}", a.Color)));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `Select`, then `Distinct`, then `Take`:

```
String.Join(",", cars.Select(a => a.Color).Distinct().Take(4)));
```

Also, `string.Join` will call `ToString` for you so you don't need to use `String.Format` (unless you really need to specially format the string).

Comment: I apoligize cause I didn't make my example detailed enough. Imagine my car object also having other properties that would pretty much make the list distinct as is. What I wound up doing is something like: String.Join(",", cars.Select(a => a.Color).Distinct().Take(4)); You led me to my answer though so thanks, I will accept this answer when I can. :)

Comment: @TMan I see, yes that would make a little bit of a difference. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `Distinct` first and then `Take(4)`

```
String.Join("," ,cars.Distinct().Take(4).Select(a => String.Format("{0}", a.Color)));
```

If your object has more properties then you can do:

```
String.Join("," ,cars.Select(r=> r.Color).Distinct().Take(4).Select(a =>a.Color));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Distinct()` will work for cars without correctly set equality comparer.
So, I guess, correct answer will be:

```
cars.Select(x => x.Color).Distinct().Take(4);
```